# Using lapply in group_by() of two factors in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply

I have this data frame (named as `OEM_final`). This is the structure:

```
str(OEM_final)
'data.frame':   2265 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ dia_hora_OEM : POSIXct, format: "2019-12-31 06:40:13" "2019-12-31 06:43:00" "2019-12-31 07:11:30" "2019-12-31 07:18:30" ...
 $ coche_OEM    : Factor w/ 6 levels "356232050832996",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 6 6 ...
 $ DTC_OEM_dec64: chr  "[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"| __truncated__ "[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"| __truncated__ "[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"| __truncated__ "[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"| __truncated__ ...
 $ rowname      : Factor w/ 2265 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 1112 1489 1600 1711 1822 1933 2044 2155 2 ...
 $ B1182        : Factor w/ 2 levels "B1182","NULL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ B124D        : Factor w/ 2 levels "B124D","NULL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ NA.          : Factor w/ 6 levels "c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 ...
 $ P2000        : Factor w/ 2 levels "c(\"P2000\", \"P2000\", \"P2000\")",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ U3003        : Factor w/ 2 levels "NULL","U3003": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ B1D01        : Factor w/ 3 levels "B1D01","c(\"B1D01\", \"B1D01\")",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ U0155        : Factor w/ 2 levels "NULL","U0155": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ C1B00        : Factor w/ 2 levels "C1B00","NULL": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ P037D        : Factor w/ 2 levels "NULL","P037D": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ P0616        : Factor w/ 2 levels "NULL","P0616": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ P0562        : Factor w/ 2 levels "NULL","P0562": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ U0073        : Factor w/ 2 levels "NULL","U0073": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ P0138        : Factor w/ 2 levels "c(\"P0138\", \"P0138\", \"P0138\")",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

I would like to calculate the earlier date (`dia_hora_OEM`) that appears when grouping by two factors. The two factors are:

- One of this factor, which is common in all the possible combinations, is `coche_OEM`.
- The other one is one from column 8 (`P2000`) to the last one (`P0138`), one at a time.

So, the `group_by()` would be:

- `group_by(coche_OEM, P2000)`
- `group_by(coche_OEM, U3003)`
- `group_by(coche_OEM, B1D01)`
- `group_by(coche_OEM, U0155)`
- ...

I tried different ways to accomplish this:

### Using `for` loops:

```
for (DTC in c(U3003, P2000)) {
  OEM_final %>%
  group_by(DTC, coche_OEM) %>%
  filter(dia_hora_OEM == min(dia_hora_OEM))
}
```

But I get an error saying:

```
Error in c(U3003, P2000) : object 'U3003' not found
```

### Using `lapply`

In this case, I created a function:

```
groupCombDTC <- function(x) {
  OEM_final %>%
  group_by(coche_OEM, x) %>%
  filter(dia_hora_OEM == min(dia_hora_OEM))
}
```

And then I ran `lapply()`:

```
lapply(colnames(OEM_final)[8:17], groupCombDTC)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Column `x` is unknown
```

Can anybody help me iterating in different combinations using `group_by()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a standard problem of standard evaluation with `dplyr`. `dplyr` is based on non standard evaluation so quoted arguments need to be unquoted.

Several solutions exist. This one works well

```r
groupCombDTC <- function(x) {
  OEM_final %>%
  group_by(coche_OEM, !!rlang::sym(x)) %>%
  filter(dia_hora_OEM == min(dia_hora_OEM))
}
```

It requires to use together `!!` and `rlang::sym` to unquote and evaluate your variable name.

Column names as arguments are easier to handle with `data.table`. If you want more elements regarding SE/NSE in `dplyr` and `data.table`, you can have a look at a [blog post](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/post/datatable/datatable-nse/) I wrote a few days ago

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the tip! Apparently it works nice!

Comment: Nice ! You have elements in the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) if it can help you