# r for loop with group_by() and assign()

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

| year | faculty | institute | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | chemistry | instituute a | 1000 |
| 2019 | life sciences | institute b | 1050 |
| 2020 | law | institute c | 2000 |
| 2018 | physics | institute d | 2100 |
| 2021 | physics | institute d | 3000 |
| 2021 | physics | institute e | 1000 |

I want to split the dataset by year, group by faculty and give each dataset a new name.
My code as far is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

#load data
publications <- read.csv("publications.csv", header = T, sep =";", encoding = 'UTF-8')

#split dataset by year
year_split <- split(publications, publications$year)
new_names_year <- c("publications2018", "publications2019",
                    "publications2020", "publications2021")
for (i in 1:length(year_split)) {
  assign(new_names_year[i], year_split[[i]])
}

#group by faculty and save as new datasets
new_names_faculty <- c("publications_faculty2018", "publications_faculty2019", 
                       "publications_faculty2020", "publications_faculty2021")
for (i in 1:length(year_split)) {
  year_split[[i]] %>%
  group_by(faculty) %>%
  summarise(
    cost = sum(cost),
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(cost)) %>% 
  assign(new_names_faculty[i], year_split[[i]])
}
```

The code is working fine until the for loop, which gives me the following error message:

```
Error in assign(., new_names_faculty[i], year_split[[i]]) : 
  invalid first argument
```

I also tried to solve the issue with lapply() based on this thread: [Using lapply in group_by() of two factors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014764/using-lapply-in-group-by-of-two-factors-in-r):

```
faculty_split <- function(x) {
  year_split %>%
  group_by(Fakultat) %>%
  summarise(
    gebucht = sum(gebucht),
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(gebucht)) %>%
  assign(new_names_faculty[i], year_split[[i]])
}
lapply(year_split, faculty_split)
```

In this case I reveice the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I would like to combine the different methods (for loop, group_by, assign) efficiently with as little code as possible.

Comment: You have `year_split[[i]] %>% ... %>% arrange(desc(cost)) %>%  assign(new_names_faculty[i], year_split[[i]])`, which is equivalent to `assign(year_split[[i]] %>% ... %>% arrange(desc(cost)), new_names_faculty[i], year_split[[i]]))`, which doesn't make sense. Change it to `year_split[[i]] %>% ... %>% arrange(desc(cost)) %>%  assign(new_names_faculty[i], .)`, using the `.` placeholder to show where you want the pipe to put its argument.

Comment: However, if you want to use "as little code as possible" skip `assign` entirely and keep things in a `list`. Name the list instead of naming objects. If you really want the objects in the global environment use `list2env`.

Comment: `year_split %>% group_by(Fakultat) ......` needs to be `x %>% group_by(Fakultat)  ......`. But I don't recommend this approach. Either keep things in one data.frame and use `group_by(year, Fakultat)`, or keep the data.frames in a list.

Comment: @GregorThomas: The placeholder solved my error message in the for loop. Working with a list is also a good solution for me as I do not need all the objects in the environment.

Comment: @Axeman: Your solution solved my error message in the lapply(), so that code works fine now too.

Comment: You may not even need to split at all then. `publications %>% group_by(year, Fakultat) %>% summarize(gebucht = sum(gebucht)) %>% arrange(year, desc(gebucht))` gets directly the sums by faculty by year.